# Union issue in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, union, union-all, proc-sql

I have met an issue about union in SAS.

1) When I run the code below:

```
proc sql;
select count(*) as cnt_obs, count(distinct user) as cnt_user from input1
union all
select count(*) as cnt_obs, count(distinct user) as cnt_user from input2
union all
select count(*) as cnt_obs, count(distinct user) as cnt_user from input3
union all
select count(*) as cnt_obs, count(distinct user) as cnt_user from input4
quit;
```

I got the result:

```
cnt_obs    cnt_user
10000000   4983437
9771110    4983438
8345177    4983438
8188069    4983438
```

2) But according to my process prior to this proc sql step, the second column of the result should be the same, so I run another code to check my result. When I run the code below:

```
proc sql;
select count(*) as cnt_obs, count(distinct user) as cnt_user from input1;
select count(*) as cnt_obs, count(distinct user) as cnt_user from input2;
select count(*) as cnt_obs, count(distinct user) as cnt_user from input3;
select count(*) as cnt_obs, count(distinct user) as cnt_user from input4;
quit;
```

I got the expected result:

```
cnt_obs    cnt_user
10000000   4983437
9771110    4983437
8345177    4983437
8188069    4983437
```

3) It seems there's an issue with UNION in SAS proc sql step, does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks very much!

Comment: I can't replicate this issue; when I try a simple test of identical code it works as expected.  If your code is as simple as you posted, I would recommend opening a track with SAS Technical Support.  If there are other complications (such as the `from inputn` being not straightforward) you may want to add those details here.

Comment: Thanks,@Joe .My code is as simple as I posted. When I use smaller datasets, the two pieces of codes above returned the same result. But when I use larger datsets, say, 10000000 observations as I posted, or more than this number, there will be a tiny bias using union all.

Comment: Can you post the log?

Comment: Sounds like you ought to open a track with tech support then.

Comment: Can't replicate... but I'd be VERY interested in knowing what SAS tech support has to say.